# Firebase: Firestore index for searching across multiple collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been banging my head on this one for days. Apologies if this is a dup.
Following the guides at https://firebase.google.com, I created `/users/` collection which has a document for each user, e.g.

```
/users/<user1>/
/users/<user2>/
```

Within each document are hundreds of fields, e.g.

```
user1 = {key1: value1, key2: value2, ..., key100: value100}
```

I want to be able to search over several fields across all the users - <strike>i.e. a collection group search, as explained in the documentation.</strike>
This is something like this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users")
    .where("key1", ">=", val1)
    .where("key2", "<=", val2)
    .where("key3, "==", "val3")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        console.log("didn't get anything?")
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("no match found: ", error);
        return false;
    });
```

I want to be able to do this for any arbitrary set of keys. Seems like firestore requires a composite index for this.
The problem is that it is not practical to create an index for each combination of keys. Say I want to be able to search up to 10 keys - this would require C(100, 1) + C(100, 2) +...+C(100, 10) number of indices, where C is the count of combinatorial choices.

I am probably thinking about it wrong, as this seems like such a common use case. As you can surmise, I want the users to be able to find other users given a set of criteria. Any advise is appreciated.

FYI, when I run the above query, I get this error:

> no match found:  FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project//firestore/indexes?create_composite=

I am developing web based app, using JavaScript, if that matters.

Comment: So did you follow the link to create the index?

Comment: Also I'm not seeing here why this requires a collection group query.  If you have just one top level collection called "users", you don't really have a collection group at all.  Just query that one collection normally as you see in the documentation.  You typically use a collection group to query subcollections of the same name.

Comment: Yes, I followed the link to create the index. The point is that my keys are dynamic so I will have to create too many indices. The user can choose any n keys to search on.

Comment: About the collectiongroup - yes, I was mistaken. I thought if I want to search for all the groups /users/user1, /users/user2, /users/user3, I would need a collectiongroup query. Editing the question to clarify that this is not a collectiongroup query.

Comment: If your keys are dynamic, then there's not much you can do except restructure your data to support queries with more predictable/regular keys.

Comment: I tried that too - by flipping the structure so that each key becomes a value in an array: arr = [key1, key2,..., key100] The problem is that the API doesn't support more than one array query. So looks like there is no way to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that due the composite index restriction, is unfeasible to search in that way.

But, maybe if you explore another way to load the collection, and the way that you are searching/iterating within the elements, you could take a different approach. .

```
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        console.log("didn't get anything?")
    })
```

I understand that the best path to perform this, is using the library, but sometimes is great to develop your own solution.

Comment: Did you mean to provide a longer example? I see only .then part